# Changes to a user doesn't show up unless i relogin

Tags: html, angular

I have a user webpage that has different info about the user like username, bio, profile pic and so on.

I've created different button that would allow me change the info and save the changes to the database but after changes the profile picture for example nothing shows up even if i reload the page but if relogin to that user account the changes finally appear which is inconvenient in real time.

My html code:

```
<body class="w3-light-grey light-blue-skin">
<header>
    <div class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-expand-lg scrolling-navbar double-nav">
      <div class="breadcrumb-dn mr-auto bread">
          <a href="/" class="mdi mdi-home mdi-36px hvr-grow-shadow new" style="text-decoration: none;"><span>Home</span></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-flex-icons ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="/offerappel" class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light hvr-grow-shadow">
            <span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block">Offre Appel</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="/" class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light hvr-grow-shadow">
            <span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block">Offre Services</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <ng-container *ngIf="loggedIn; else elseTemplate">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light hvr-grow-shadow dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">{{loginUser.username}}</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a href="/myaccount" class="dropdown-item" style="cursor: pointer;">My Account</a>
              <a (click)="logout()" class="dropdown-item" style="cursor: pointer;">Logout</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #elseTemplate>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/auth/login" class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light hvr-grow-shadow">
                  <span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block">Login</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/auth/register" class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light hvr-grow-shadow">
                  <span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block">Register</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ng-template>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="w3-content w3-margin-top" style="max-width:1400px; margin-top: 150px !important">
<div class="w3-row-padding">
  <div class="w3-third">

    <div class="w3-white w3-text-grey w3-card-4">
      <div class="w3-display-container">
        <img [src]="imgSrc" class="mat-elevation-z5" style="width: 200px; border-radius: 50px; margin-bottom: 45px; position: relative; margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 10px; height: 250px" alt="Avatar">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
          <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)">
          </label>
          <button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!selectedFiles" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
        </div>
          <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-container w3-text-black"  style="position: relative; margin-bottom: 20px">
          <h2>{{loginUser.username}}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-container">
          <button mat-raised-button (click)="info()" style="float: right; width: 50px"><i class="fa fa-cog w3-margin-right w3-xxlarge w3-text-teal" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <div id="userinfo" style="display: block">
        <p><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-large w3-text-teal"></i>{{loginUser.location | uppercase}}</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-large w3-text-teal"></i>{{loginUser.email}}</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-large w3-text-teal"></i>{{loginUser.number}}</p>
        </div>
        <div id="edituserinfo" style="display: none">
          <form [formGroup]="infoForm" (ngSubmit)="editINFO()">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="Location" formControlName="location">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="Phone Number" formControlName="phoneNumber">
            </mat-form-field>
            <button mat-raised-button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="round" style="margin-top: -20px">
            <a class="button" (click)="goBack()">Account Info</a>
          </div>
          <div class="round" >
            <ng-container *ngIf="role === 'ROLE_CLIENT'; else elseTemplate">
              <a class="button" style="top: -20px" (click)="goToOffers()">Offre Appel</a>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-template #elseTemplate>
              <a class="button" style="top: -20px" (click)="goToOffers()">Offre Service</a>
            </ng-template>
          </div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div><br>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-twothird" id="account-info">

    <div class="w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-margin-bottom">
      <div>
      <h2 class="w3-text-grey w3-padding-16" style="float: inline-start"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-xxlarge w3-text-teal" aria-hidden="true"></i>Bio</h2>
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="bio()" style="float: right; width: 50px; margin-top: 17px;"><i class="fa fa-cog w3-margin-right w3-xxlarge w3-text-teal" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <div id="showBIO" style="display: block">
        <span>{{loginUser.bio}}</span>
        <hr>
        </div>
        <div id="editBIO" style="display: none">
        <form [formGroup]="editBioForm" (ngSubmit)="editBio()">
          <textarea placeholder="enter your bio." formControlName="bio" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
          <button mat-raised-button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2 class="w3-text-grey w3-padding-16"><i class="fa fa-suitcase fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-xxlarge w3-text-teal"></i>Work Experience</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="offers" style="display: none" class="w3-twothird">
      <div class="w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-margin-bottom">
        <h4 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 100px; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: -40px">Offer List</h4>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addOfferForm()">
              <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 5px"></i> Add
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="newOffer" style="display: none">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                <form [formGroup]="offerForm" (ngSubmit)="addOffer()">
                  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                    <label style="font-weight: 600; margin-right: 50px; font-size: 1rem">Offer Name</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="offername" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                      <label style="font-weight: 600; margin-right: 50px; font-size: 1rem">Description</label>
                      <textarea formControlName="description" class="form-control" cols="40" rows="9"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                      <label style="font-weight: 600; margin-right: 50px; font-size: 1rem">Contact</label>
                      <input type="text" formControlName="contact" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                      <label style="font-weight: 600; margin-right: 50px; font-size: 1rem">Location</label>
                      <input type="text" formControlName="location" class="form-control"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                      <label style="font-weight: 600; margin-right: 50px; font-size: 1rem">Salary</label>
                      <input type="text" formControlName="prix" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                      <label style="font-weight: 600; margin-right: 50px; font-size: 1rem">Category:</label>
                    <select formControlName="services" style="width: 150px">
                      <option *ngFor="let s of allServices" [ngValue]="s">{{s.serviceName}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="offerList" style="line-height: 2; width: 750px;">
        <div *ngFor="let mf of myOffers" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" >
          <div style="height: 140px; border-radius: 20px; background-color: white" class="mat-elevation-z5">
            <div style="margin-left: 15px;">
              <div>
                <h6 style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 20px;">{{mf.offername}}</h6>
              </div>
                <p style="margin-top: 15px;">{{mf.description | reverseStr}}</p>
                <p>{{mf.dateCreation | date: shortDate}}</p>
                <div style="margin-left: 90px; margin-top: -46px">
                  <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <span>{{mf.location}}</span>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left: 190px; margin-top: -31px">
                    <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <span>{{mf.contact}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's the ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UploadFileServiceService } from '../upload-file-service.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nacc',
  templateUrl: './nacc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nacc.component.scss']
})
export class NaccComponent implements OnInit {
  loggedIn: boolean;
  loginUser: any = {};
  role: any;
  offers: any[] = [];
  myOffers: any[] = [];
  imgSrc: any;
  progress: { percentage: number} = { percentage : 0};
  currentFileUpload: File;
  selectedFiles: FileList;
  editBioForm: FormGroup;
  infoForm: FormGroup;
  offerForm: FormGroup;
  allServices: any[] = [];
  constructor(private service: UserService,
          private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
          private http: HttpClient,
          private uploadservice: UploadFileServiceService,
          private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser') === null) {
      this.loggedIn = false;
    } else {
      this.loggedIn = true;
      this.loginUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    }
    console.log(this.loginUser);
    this.role = this.loginUser.roles[0];
    this.service.getAllOffer().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.offers = res;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.offers.length; i++) {
        const element = this.offers[i];
        if (this.loginUser.id === element.user.id) {
          this.myOffers.push(element);
        }
      }
      if (this.loginUser.photo === 'http://localhost:8082/static.images/user/default.jpg') {
        console.log('something');
      } else {
        this.getImage('http://localhost:8082/downloadFile/' + this.loginUser.photo).subscribe(data => {
        this.createImageFromBlob(data);
      });
    }
  });
  this.service.getServices().subscribe(res => {
    this.allServices = res;
  });
  this.editBioForm = this.fb.group({
    bio: ['']
  });
  this.infoForm = this.fb.group({
    location: [''],
    phoneNumber: ['']
  });
  this.offerForm = this.fb.group({
    type: [''],
    offername: [''],
    description: [''],
    contact: [''],
    location: [''],
    prix: [''],
    user: [''],
    services: ['']
  });
}
get d() {
  return this.offerForm.controls;
}
addOffer() {
  this.offerForm.get('user').setValue(this.loginUser);
  for (let i = 0; i < this.allServices.length; i++) {
    const element = this.allServices[i];
    console.log('element', element);
    console.log('serviceId: ', (this.offerForm.get('services').value));
    if (Number(this.offerForm.get('services').value) === element.serviceName) {
      this.offerForm.get('services').setValue(element);
    }
  }
  if (this.role === 'ROLE_CLIENT') {
    this.offerForm.get('type').setValue('OA');
  } else if (this.role === 'ROLE_PRESTATEUR') {
    this.offerForm.get('type').setValue('OS');
  }
  console.log('form: ', this.offerForm.value);
  this.service.addOffer(this.offerForm.value, this.loginUser.token).subscribe(res => {
    console.log('yeeeeeeet');
    document.getElementById('newOffer').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('offerList').style.display = 'block';
    location.reload();
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
  return this.http.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'blob'});
}
createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
    this.imgSrc = reader.result;
}, false);
  if (image) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
  }
}

logout() {
  localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  location.reload();
}

upload() {
  const token = this.loginUser.token;
  console.log(token);
  this.progress.percentage = 0;
  this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
  this.uploadservice.pushFileToStorage(this.currentFileUpload, token).subscribe(event => {
  if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
    this.progress.percentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
  } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
  }
});
this.selectedFiles = undefined;
}

public onFileSelected(event: EventEmitter<File[]>) {
const file: File = event[0];
console.log(file);
}
selectFile(event) {
  this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
}

bio() {
  document.getElementById('showBIO').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('editBIO').style.display = 'block';
}

editBio() {
  this.service.editUser(this.editBioForm.value, this.loginUser.token).subscribe(res => {
  location.reload();
}
);
}

info() {
  document.getElementById('userinfo').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('edituserinfo').style.display = 'block';
}

editINFO() {
  this.service.editUser(this.infoForm.value, this.loginUser.token).subscribe(res => {
  location.reload();
}
);
}

goToOffers() {
  document.getElementById('account-info').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('offers').style.display = 'block';
}

goBack() {
  document.getElementById('account-info').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('offers').style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `localStorage.setItem('currentUser', ...)` ?

Comment: I didn't add it

Comment: You're setting `this.loginUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));` so if you're never updating that localStorage value then your loginUser value isn't going to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your editINFO method like below to update the localstorage when you are done editing info, assuming you return the updated user info instance that you get when you login. :

```
editINFO() {
 this.service.editUser(this.infoForm.value, this.loginUser.token).subscribe(res => {
 localStorage.setItem('currentUser', res ); // Provided you are returning the user info 
 on update.
 location.reload();
 });
}
```